# Why do I get this error when installing Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip, jupyter-notebook

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\nithi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\nithi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\nithi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpba_qtkcq'
       cwd: C:\Users\nithi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dq1r1ff8\argon2-cffi
  Complete output (25 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\low_level.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_ffi_build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_legacy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_password_hasher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  running build_clib
  building 'argon2' library
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2\src\blake2
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iextras\libargon2\src\..\include -Iextras\libargon2\src\blake2 -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include /Tcextras\libargon2\src\argon2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2\src\argon2.obj
  argon2.c
  extras\libargon2\src\argon2.c(18): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi
Failed to build argon2-cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for argon2-cffi which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I keep getting this error when I try to install jupyter notebook.
pip install notebook, this is the command I used on the command line.
One website suggested to install visual studio C++, Which I did and still no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thank you