# Error in pip install in Python 3.9 related to Visual Studio

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, pip

I have an error while installing jupyter-notebook in Pycharm terminal on Windows:

```py
pip install notebook
```

Currently I use Python 3.9

I have tried to install in Pycharm's terminal with/without administrator permisions.

I have tried to install in console with/without administrator permisions.

I have tried to reinstall Python 3.9.

I think there are some problems with **Visual Studio**, because the message displays the Visual Studio 2019 directory. But why? I launched pip install in PyCharm terminal, I didn't open Visual Studio in this time.
One of the last rows in error message:

```
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

Full displayed message:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pywinpty
  Building wheel for pywinpty (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\пк\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e2
xrfsm7\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e2xrfsm7\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=
f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-hv58iobu'
       cwd: C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e2xrfsm7\pywinpty\
  Complete output (25 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
  copying winpty\ptyprocess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
  copying winpty\winpty_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
  copying winpty\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
  copying winpty\tests\test_cywinpty.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
  copying winpty\tests\test_ptyprocess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
  copying winpty\tests\test_winpty_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
  copying winpty\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\_winpty
  copying winpty\_winpty\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\_winpty
  running build_ext
  building 'winpty.cywinpty' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\winpty
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\пк\appdata\local\programs\p
ython\python39\include -Ic:\users\пк\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\includ
e -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\
Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Progra
m Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcwinpty/cywinpty.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\wi
npty/cywinpty.obj
  cywinpty.c
  winpty/cywinpty.c(629): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pywinpty
  Running setup.py clean for pywinpty
Failed to build pywinpty
Installing collected packages: pywinpty, terminado, notebook
    Running setup.py install for pywinpty ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\пк\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-
e2xrfsm7\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e2xrfsm7\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);cod
e=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y8q1qlob\install-reco
rd.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\пк\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pywinpty'
         cwd: C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e2xrfsm7\pywinpty\
    Complete output (25 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
    copying winpty\ptyprocess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
    copying winpty\winpty_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
    copying winpty\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\test_cywinpty.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\test_ptyprocess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\test_winpty_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\_winpty
    copying winpty\_winpty\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\winpty\_winpty
    running build_ext
    building 'winpty.cywinpty' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\winpty
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\пк\appdata\local\programs
\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\пк\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\incl
ude -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86
)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcwinpty/cywinpty.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\
winpty/cywinpty.obj
    cywinpty.c
    winpty/cywinpty.c(629): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\пк\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ПК\\A
ppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e2xrfsm7\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e2xrfsm7\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"
'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Temp
\pip-record-y8q1qlob\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\пк\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pywinpty' Check the lo
gs for full command output.
```

There are related unanswered questions:
[Why do I get this error when installing Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481601/why-do-i-get-this-error-when-installing-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: install pipwin and then use pipwin install notebook